# Create a new column in a dataframe with increment number based on another column

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

Consider the below pandas DataFrame:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': [Timestamp('2017-03-27'),
            Timestamp('2017-03-27'),
            Timestamp('2017-04-01'),
            Timestamp('2017-04-03'),
            Timestamp('2017-04-06'),
            Timestamp('2017-04-07'),
            Timestamp('2017-04-11'),
            Timestamp('2017-05-01'),
            Timestamp('2017-05-01')],
 'act_id': ['916298883', 
            '916806776',
            '923496071',
            '926539428',
            '930641527',
            '931935227',
            '937765185',
            '966163233',
            '966417205'] 
})
```

As you may see, there are 9 unique ids distributed in 7 days.

I am looking for a way to add two new columns.

- The first column:

> An increment number for each new day. For example 1 for '2017-03-27'(same number for same day), 2 for '2017-04-01', 3 for '2017-04-03', etc.

- The second column:

> An increment number for each new act_id per day. For example 1 for '916298883', 2 for '916806776' (which is linked to the same day '2017-03-27'), 1 for '923496071', 1 for '926539428', etc.

The final table should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGzcI.png)

I have already tried to build the first column with apply and a function but it doesn't work as it should.

```
#Create helper function to give index number to a new column
counter = 1
def giveFlag(x):
    global counter
    index = counter
    counter+=1
    return index
```

And then:
    `# Create day flagger column`
    `df_helper['day_no'] = df_helper['day'].apply(lambda x: giveFlag(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
days = list(set(df['day']))
days.sort()
day_no = list()
iter_no = list()
for index,day in enumerate(days):
    counter=1
    for dfday in df['day']:
        if dfday == day:
            iter_no.append(counter)
            day_no.append(index+1)
            counter+=1

df['day_no'] = pd.Series(day_no).values
df['iter_no'] = pd.Series(iter_no).values
```

Comment: Thank you! You made it simpler then I was expecting.